# How to keep circular reference, when stringifying JS object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, circular-reference

I am working on a filetree-like object that is:

```
var object = {
    'name':'foo',
    'contains': {'thisObject': object,'parentObject': /* the object that contains the current object*/, 'foo':'bar'},
    'parent': /* the object that contains the current object*/
}
```

It may look a bit weird, but there's a reason for it looking like this.

It is user determined, so it can end up like this:

```
object.contains["foo"].contains["bar"].contains["biz"].contains["frt"]...
```

I need to somehow save that to the users computer. Right now, I was using localStorage and `JSON.stringify()`. But this way, JSON fails on Circular Structure Error.

How can I save it while maintaining the Circular Structure?
Is there a better way than localStorage/JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Have you tried a library that allows circular references?

One good one is DOJO.
https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/

From its instructions:

```
var obj = {};
obj.me = obj;
var jsonWithCircularRef = dojox.json.ref.toJson(obj);
```